# Add read-only property to a certain character

Tags: emacs, readonly

I'm trying add the `read-only` property to all characters of a certain type in the current buffer.

For instance, suppose I had a buffer with text deliminated by pipes `|` like so:

`| this is just a test | the real buffer | is much more complex |`

I want to make the `|` read only as to effectively limit the region in which the user can type. My first guess how to do this was to do something with multiple cursors, like:

```
(search-forward "|")
(set-mark (point))
(left-char)
(mc/mark-all-like-this)
(add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(read-only t))
```

however, this only applies the property to the first character highlighted. In other words, the read only property doesn't extend to all of the `|`'s. Is there a more concise way of doing this? Or do I have to brute-force search all of the pipes and add the property one-by-one?

Comment: What is `mc/mark-all-like-this`? The search puts point *after* the `|`, so if you want to set the region around that char then you need to use `(point)` and `(1- (point))`, and there should be no need for `right-char` (since you are already after the `|`. And you need to iterate - put the search and add property in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, syntactical error on my part. The question still stands though.

Comment: And okay, I'll try to iterate. Thanks